# In Bolt CMS, is it possible to check role membership in a controller?

Tags: php, bolt-cms

I'm trying to add some functionality to the back end of a Bolt CMS installation that does the following:

1. Check if the user is a member of the "limited editor" group.
2. If so, only list content which they, personally, own.

This needs to be within the controller, not using Twig.

I've got the user object using

$user = $app['users']->getCurrentUser();

I guess I could use

in_array('limitededitor', $user["roles"]);

But I wondered if there was any existing function in Bolt that would streamline this, like "isAllowed" but for checking role membership?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've used in the past to determine whether I mount a controller (and thus give access to the new urls), the key part is the users service has a `hasRole` method but you need to check by user id.

`public function checkAuth()
    {
        $currentUser = $this->app['users']->getCurrentUser();
        $currentUserId = $currentUser['id'];
        foreach (['admin', 'root', 'developer', 'editor'] as $role) {
            if ($this->app['users']->hasRole($currentUserId, $role)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }`